# web site deployment issue

Tags: c#, .net, iis, deployment, dns

My development/deployment environment is, IIS + Windows Server 2003/2008 + .Net + VSTS2008 + C#. I have several web sites, each of them has stable and beta version, for example, I have beta version order system and stable version order system, the same as purchase system. I deployed the 4 systems on 4 different physical machines.

My requirement is, I want to have a common URL schema to access the different systems, like,

```
http://www.mycorp.com/order/beta
http://www.mycorp.com/order/stable
http://www.mycorp.com/purchase/beta
http://www.mycorp.com/purchase/stable
```

But since the 4 systems are deployed on 4 different physical machines with different machine/DNS name, how could I map the same domain (http://www.mycorp.com) with different suffix to different physical online systems?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like:

> http://orderbeta.mycorp.com
>
> http://orderstable.mycorp.com

Obviously with better names than that. :-)

Comment: Becaue of business requirement, any ideas of solution for my original question?

Comment: Strange business requirement. I can't see what the business benefit of using this over sub domains would be. I recommend you look into ISA server as Nir Levy has suggested or consider having one Webserver that redirects to the others. Personally I would go down the sub domain route, as a "technical limitation".

Comment: Thanks @RichardOD, I have taken 2 hours to read ISA server tutorials but not find speciifc solution for my problem. Appreciate if you could recommend some documents which solve my specific problem?

Comment: Ignoring firewall requirements etc, can't you just have all of your "sites" as virtual directories on 1 IIS server and then redirect to the others?

Comment: No, I need to isolate them physically. Any recommended ISA server documents speicifc to my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) to do this. for MS based system you can use either ISA or apache or squid. Take note that it's a complicated setup if you have not done that before and might take a few days to get things done production level.

If you are flexible you can use dev.mydomain.com etc. as suggested above.

Comment: I have used reverse proxy server before, but one physical server with one reverse proxy server to cache the request/response to the specific server. How to use reverse proxy server to map address as I mentioned in my original post, looks like the URL you referred also does not mention this issue.

Comment: the following explains it for apache: http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies